# MLE for Poisson Process

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, poisson-process, capture-mark-recapture

I asked a similar question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/492539/poisson-process-method-of-moments) regarding method of moments, and now I need to figure out how to solve using MLE.

Here is a repeat of the problem:

> A School of Ornithology researcher wants to estimate the number of red-tailed hawks in Ithaca. She radio tags 10 birds, and then sets up a feeding station with automatic camera

> The researcher believes that each individual bird's visits to the feeder can be modeled as a Poisson process with some unknown rate $\lambda$. Over the first five weeks, she observes an average of 28.8 birds (tagged and untagged) visiting the feeder, with an average of 6 tagged birds per week.

> Next, she develops a video processing program which can identify and distinguish different individual birds from their pictures. Using this, over the next week, she observes 20 unique birds visiting the feeding station, out of which 4 are tagged. What is the MLE for the size of the hawk population in Ithaca?

Here is what I have so far:
We want to know what the distribution of number of tagged birds out of unique visitors in a week is. P(a given hawk visits at least one time) = 1 - P(no visits) = $1 - \frac{\lambda^0e^{-\lambda}}{0!}= 1 - e^{-\lambda}$. Let $p = 1 - e^{-\lambda}$. Then we see that the number of unique hawks to appear in a given week follows a binomial distribution with probability $p$. Then $L(\theta | D) = \prod_{i=1}^{10} {10 \choose k_i} p^{k_i}(1-p)^{10-k_i}$. We know from theory that MLE for a binomial is $p = \tfrac xn$ where $x$ is number of successes and $n$ is total trials. So here $p = \frac{4}{10}$. Which implies $1-e^{-\lambda} = \frac{4}{10} \implies \lambda = -\ln(\frac{6}{10})$

Assuming my logic is correct, I am not sure how to use $\lambda$ to infer about the total population.

Edit: I have attempted this:
We know that the population is now a sum of $N$ bernoulli trials, i.e. binomial with probability $p = \frac{20}{N} = 1 - e^{-\lambda} = \frac{4}{10} \implies N = 50$ hawks.

This is close to using Method moments of my original problem which estimated 48 hawks. Does this logic seem correct?

Comment: How would you relate the Poisson parameter to the *size of the population,* which is what you are asked to estimate?  This looks like a hypergeometric problem to me.

Comment: The sum of poisson processes is poisson no?

Comment: Why would a Poisson process be relevant here? The hawk population is finite and so there is an upper limit to the number of unique birds that might visit the feeding station during any period, no matter how long it might be -- but no Poisson process has any such upper limit.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to mention that the bird arrivals to the feeder are defined as a Poisson process with $\lambda$. I have added it to the problem

Comment: That may be so, but it's not relevant for the reasons I gave in my previous comment.  This question asks about *unique* birds within a *finite population.*

Comment: How would that be different from the original problem? I am struggling with what uniqueness has to do with it.